# create-react-app bash: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I had an origonal problem that I tried to fix and got another problem

**1. ORIGONAL PROBLEM**
I just tried to install a new react app using create-react-app and got this error first

```
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
```

The node modules were installed but none of the other files or directories that normally install.

**2. What I did to fix Origonal problem**
on the react app website it https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/  it was suggested that I do the following (which I did)

"If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version."

I tried to run the command npm uninstall -g create-react-app  but could not do it as my mac prevented it so ran sudo  npm uninstall -g create-react-app

**3. New PROBLEM**

When I now run create-react-app I get the message

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app: No such file or directory
TDI-MacBook-Air:Active bob$
```

What do I need to do to get create react App back. I am worried about messing up my installation more so am hesitant to go at it without some advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simply run `npx create-react-app app_name` to create your app. 
`npx` will fetch the latest version of create-react-app and setup your app.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my error Just simply run `npx create-react-app app_name` to create your app. npx will fetch the latest version of create-react-app and setup your app.